# Rename a field which was Primary Key in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with the following fields:

```
email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    department              = models.TextField(verbose_name="department")
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    emp_id                  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hide_email              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name                    = models.TextField(verbose_name="employee name")
```

I want to rename "emp_id" field to "id", as you can see it is the primary key field. Can you please create a migration file for the same?

Thank you

Comment: You should rename/remove the field in the model and let Django create the migration. Without doing this, Django will keep reverting the migration back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify the field to:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …,
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='emp_id')
    # …
```

If you then run `manage.py makemigrations`, Django will ask if you renamed the fied:

> ```
> Did you rename mymodel.emp_id to mymodel.id (a AutoField)? [y/N]
> ```

a question you answer with <kbd>y</kbd>es.

This will still use the `emp_id` as the database id. If you want to rename the database column as well, you can just remove the `emp_id` field, and Django will use the default `id` field as primary key instead, and you can let Django make migrations the same way.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app_name', 'name_of_previousmigration_file'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='modelname',
            name='emp_id',
        )
    ]
```

Comment: Can I rename it instead? Because I think I might lose the primary key values.

Comment: after removing, Django will use the default id field as primary key instead. you can never lose primary key values. without them db table won't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # other fields
```

Then run **python manage.py makemigrations**

A message will appear which will tell you to confirm that you want to rename the field **emp_id** to **id**. Type **y** to confirm yes.

Then run **python manage.py migrate**

In you application directory you'll found migration files.